# pyethapp installation issue on OSX 10.13.2

Tags: macos, python-2.7

Installing pyethapp in virtual environment on OSX 10.13.2 with following properties:

- Python 2.7.14 pip (9.0.1) setuptools (38.2.4) wheel (0.30.0)

and get following error message:

```
Collecting pyethapp
  Using cached pyethapp-1.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting ethereum>=1.5.1 (from pyethapp)
  Using cached ethereum-2.2.0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    error in ethereum setup command: 'tests_require' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers; Unordered types are not allowed
```

Any idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 5):

I have the same issue on Arch Linux.

It looks like `setup.py tests_require` uses a set which is not support in `setuptools > 38.0`.

It should be.

```
pip install setuptools==37
```

This trick works for me.

Greetings.

Comment: This is not an Answer to the asked question. If you have the issue please ask a new Question.

Comment: This fixed the issue.